# Belkin Wireless G router not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-router

I have a Belkin F5D7230-4 Wireless G router which used to work on XP. I have a clean Windows 7 install (on the same **desktop** PC), and it just won't work.

Device Manager lists the adapter as a USB device, but it says "The drivers for this device are not installed", even though the driver installer said the installation was OK.

Manage Wiresless Networks says "wireless is not currently enabled". The WLAN AutoConfig service is running.

My specific question is which of the two symptoms above should I go for first? Should I try to fix the driver installation somehow, or should I try to enable wireless? Is one caused by the other, or is this two independent problems?

Any other thoughs that could help me are also appreciated.

Comment: Is the device on the computer a USB device or is it a device integrated in the computer?

Comment: It's a USB device.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about a wireless router or a wireless usb adapter?

Comment: Problem solved. I mistakenly assumed that the network USB adapter and the wireless router were the same thing, and thought that I had the latest driver. Here is a description on how to make it work:

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/34323-belkin-f5d7050.html

Answer (score 1):

Check whether:

- the USB adapter has the proper Windows 7 drivers
- Device Manager shows anything, e.g. any exclamation mark or X
- there is an installer or updated driver package for the USB device from the vendor's homepage

If the adapter is not working, you can't enable wireless networking.

Comment: There is a small exclamation mark on yellow background on the USB2.0 WLAN icon. I'm not sure about the proper Windows 7 drivers. The installer didn't complain about running on Windows 7, but DM says no driver is installed. I will try to find the latest driver, but I found Belkin's site a bit hard to navigate.